# Issue Rebind NInject while dynamically change the connection string

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

In connection string i should dynamically passing the loggeduserid value by using the attribute application name=userid in connection string and getting into SQL Server by using the query select app_name().

Technologies used:
1).net 4.0
2)NHibernate
3)Ninject

Before logged-in i am using Ninject IoC container and NHibernate to load the connection string without the application name attribute and after logged in I am passing the logged user id as a constructor value and rebinding the NhibernateConfiguration class is as follows

Before Logged in inject the NHibernateConfiguration

```
public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<NHibernateConfiguration>()
                                               .GetSessionFactory()
                                               .OpenSession());

            Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<NHibernateConfiguration>().GetSessionFactory());

        }
```

After logged in passing the loggeduserid with the constructor argument is as follows.

```
using (var kernal = ServiceLocator.GetKernel())
{
 kernal.Rebind<NHibernateConfiguration>().To<NHibernateConfiguration>()
.WithConstructorArgument("loggedUserId", user.Id);
}
```

but I am not able rebind or inject the NHibernateConfiguration class .

Please help me how to rebind the NHibernateConfiguration class by using Ninject

Comment: in your example you havent actually bound NHibernateConfiguration at all (you need to call .Bind before you can call .Rebind), also on a sidenote, Ninject isnt really a service locator even though it can be used as one, normally ninject gets used in constructor/parameter injection scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Don't use rebind during the execution of your application. This can cause many problems. Use conditional bidnings instead:

```
kernel.Bind<NHibernateConfiguration>().To<NHibernateConfiguration>();
kernel.Bind<NHibernateConfiguration>().To<NHibernateConfiguration>()
      .When(ctx => IsLoggedIn())
      .WithConstructorArgument("loggedUserId", request => user.Id);

private bool IsLoggedIn()
{
     // add code to decide if the user is logged in
}
```

Also your session binding doesn't make much sense. It should get the session factory instead.

```
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>()
                .OpenSession());
```