# Ninject Contextual Binding on MVC Request

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an unusual situation injecting a service into an ASP.NET MVC Controller.  The Controller provides a single action to render a side-bar menu on the page, and the service injected into the Controller is a factory to create the side-bar content.  The action is decorated with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute: the side bar can only be rendered when rendering another action.

The difficulty comes in that I want to inject different instances of the side-bar factory abstraction according to the page (= Controller) being requested.  Previously, I was doing this using a sort-of abstract factory, which had the inelegant implementation of using the controller name string to determine which concrete factory implementation to use; I've now moved this to a proper abstract factory, and thus need to move the selection of the factory type elsewhere.

My Ninject bindings are currently defined very simply as:

```
Kernel.Bind<ISideBarFactory>().To<FooSideBarFactory>().InRequestScope();
Kernel.Bind<ISideBarFactory>().To<DefaultSideBarFactory>().InRequestScope();
```

and as I add more controllers, I will add more instances of the first line.  The way I would like to see this working is:

- `/foo/action` request received

  - Ninject binds `ISideBarFactory` to `FooSideBarFactory` and injects into `SideBarController`
- `/bar/action` request received

  - Ninject binds `ISideBarFactory` to `BarSideBarFactory` and injects into `SideBarController`
- `/baz/action` request received

  - No `BazSideBarFactory` exists, so Ninject binds `ISideBarFactory` to the default implementation, `DefaultSideBarFactory`, and injects into `SideBarController`

I've consulted the Ninject wiki page on [Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding), which appears to be what I want *in principle*, but I haven't found anything documented there which obviously achieves my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine reading the route data with [Contextual-Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

**Binding**

```
// default binding - used if none of the conditions is met
kernel.Bind<IService>()
    .To<DefaultService>()

kernel.Bind<IService>()
    .To<BasicService>()
    .When(x=> IsRouteValueDefined("controller", "Service"));

kernel.Bind<IService>()
    .To<ExtraService>()
    .When(x=> IsRouteValueDefined("controller", "ExtraService"));
```

**`IsRouteValueDefined()` method**

*Returns true when route key is defined and specified `routeValue` equals route value for route key or is `null`.*

```
public static bool IsRouteValueDefined(string routeKey, string routeValue)
{
    var mvcHanlder = (MvcHandler)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    var routeValues = mvcHanlder.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
    var containsRouteKey = routeValues.ContainsKey(routeKey);
    if (routeValue == null)
        return containsRouteKey;
    return containsRouteKey && routeValues[routeKey].ToString().ToUpper() == routeValue.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: This looks to get me on the right track, thanks. What I now need is a way to say "Bind IService to BasicService if the contextual bindings didn't match."

Comment: It is not recommended to use `Rebind` at runtime. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9209932/1193333 . And I would definetly go with @Remo . Instead, just create default binding, without `When` condition. Ninject first tries to resolve `When` conditions and if all fails, then it goes for default binding. See my updated answer.

Comment: Interesting; I don't think I could get it working that way earlier, but I'll give it another go. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: Just tried it again, and I was right. If using the solution you proposed, I get an `ActivationException` with message "More than one matching bindings are available.": it can resolve to either the DefaultService on the catch-all binding, or the specific service matched on the appropriate contextual binding. (Ninject 3.0)

Comment: Just installed asp-mvc 3 with Ninject 3 and it works as expected for me. Assure, that multiple conditions cannot be met at once.

Comment: I only have one condition (`.When(_ => RequestedControllerIs("foo"))`), and the default binding. The only differences between my code and your sample code are binding `.InRequestScope()`, and a modification to only check the controller name rather than any arbitrary route value.

Comment: `InRequestScope()` does not matter. Are you sure, that `RequestedControllerIs("foo")` does not return true even for controller `"bar"`?

Comment: Ok, seems like the Ninject mailing list would be a better place to continue this discussion. Thanks for your help.