# Conditional binding in WebApi2 controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using Ninject with the following packages:

- Ninject
- Ninject.MVC5
- Ninject.Web.Common (and Common.WebHost)
- Ninject.Web.WebApi (and WebApi.WebHost)

I have a WebApi2 Controller that looks like the below.  My `Get()` method must be performant and it doesn't depend on the value of `IMyFooService`, thus I don't care if it gets injected or not when `Get()` is requested.

**Question:**

Is there a way for me to selectively bind interfaces only if certain api methods are called?  Whether through using attributes or...?

```
public class FooController : ApiController {

    public IMyFooService fooService;

    public FooController(IMyFooService fooService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    [NonDependent] // Don't really care about the value of fooService
    public JsonResult Get() {}

    [Dependent] // Must have valid dependency injection
    public async Task<JsonResult> Post([FromBody] IList foos) {
        var didMyFoo = this.fooService.DoTheFoo();
    }
}
```

Here is my `NinjectWebCommon.cs`:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IMyFooService>().To<MyConcreteService>().InRequestScope();
}
```

I noticed that `To<T>()` has many `.When()` options.  Perhaps I can make use of this to say `.When(/* Controller = Foo, Action = Post */)`.

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-core-lazy-command-pattern/ some one has already suggested something similar but I believe this is the design you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest, and probably most succinct, way is to use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) which was made exactly for this use case - quoting from the docs:

> Use lazy initialization to defer the creation of a large or
>   resource-intensive object, or the execution of a resource-intensive
>   task, particularly when such creation or execution might not occur
>   during the lifetime of the program.

Support for `Lazy<T>` injection comes with [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/) (also see it's Wiki Page on [`Lazy<T>`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Lazy)). Install it's [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/) and you should be ready to inject `Lazy<T>`.

Adapt the code of your controller as follows:

```
public class FooController : ApiController {

    public Lazy<IMyFooService> fooService;

    public FooController(Lazy<IMyFooService> fooService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    public JsonResult Get() {}

    public async Task<JsonResult> Post([FromBody] IList foos) {
        var didMyFoo = this.fooService.Value.DoTheFoo();
    }
}
```

Please notice that the actual service is accessed by the **`.Value`** Property on `Lazy<T>`. On first access to this property the instance is retrieved.

Comment: Yes, for this particular case assuming that initialization of MyConcreteService is quite heavy operation which you would like to skip where it's not needed, I would say Lazy is the best option. I'm jealous this thought didn't come to my mind instead of directly answering the question :) This should be marked as correct answer for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has been asked some time ago. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823176/ninject-contextual-binding-on-mvc-request) out. So for you particular case you can just modify IsRouteValueDefined method (you can think about some better naming, I would suggest something like IsRoutePoitingTo) from original answer to something like this (you might revisit if that works for WebApi, but for sure there is a way to get current route for that as well):

```
public static bool IsRouteValueDefined(string controller, string action)
{
    var mvcHanlder = (MvcHandler)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    var routeValues = mvcHanlder.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
    var containsRouteKey = routeValues.ContainsKey(routeKey);
    if (routeValue == null)
        return containsRouteKey;

    return containsRouteKey &&
           routeValues["controller"].ToString().Equals(controller, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
           routeValues["action"].ToString().Equals(action, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

And binding will look like:

```
kernel.Bind<IMyFooService>()
      .To<MyConcreteService>()
      .When(x=> IsRouteValueDefined("foo", "get"));
```

Just not sure about "get" as for ApiController the actual route could be http://website.com/foo/, if so, simply use string.Empty as "action" param. You can check that with your particular project. As you don't need default injection (which is present in original answer) - I just dropped that.